# Update statement based on select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-update

I have statement

```
update Clients
set StatusID= 4
from (select c.clientid
from Clients c
where CategCode = 'CH' and StatusID in (1,2,6) and DATEDIFF(YEAR,dob,GETDATE())>5)
```

it throwing me error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

do you see what can cause this error?

I was trying to use this statement but it set status 4 for all clients

```
update Clients
set StatusID= 4
WHERE EXISTS( 
select clientid,DOB,DATEDIFF(YEAR,dob,GETDATE())
from Clients 
where CategCode = 'CH' and StatusID in (1,2,6) and DATEDIFF(YEAR,dob,GETDATE())>5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
update c
set c.StatusID= 4
from Clients c
where CategCode = 'CH' and StatusID in (1,2,6) 
and DATEDIFF(YEAR,dob,GETDATE())>5
```

Your 2nd query should be

```
update c
set StatusID= 4
from Clients c
WHERE EXISTS( 
select 1
from Clients x
where CategCode = 'CH' and StatusID in (1,2,6)  and x.clientid = c.clientid)
```

Comment: throwing error `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.`

Comment: do not recognize this part `x.clienid = c.cliendid`